# Simultaneous, synchronous content streaming

Tags: java, python, network-programming, streaming, video-streaming

I'm trying to build a media player that can synchronously stream video content. What I want to achieve is for several people to simultaneously watching the same movie from different location, and if one client pauses the movie, it will be paused for everyone. Somewhat similar to how gamers stream their games to the viewers, only that the streaming content would be some video file.

Can someone recommend any documentation or point me into the right direction? Programming language wise I would prefer either `Python`, `Ruby`, `Objective-C`, or `Java`. I would probably have to use `TCP` to ensure the correct order, but how to deal with user inputs, e.g. pause, play, etc.?

EDIT: I just found a website that does exactly what I'm trying to achieve. This is an example of what I would like to make for my own server: [Sync-Video.com](http://sync-video.com/)

I found some nice solutions on GitHub. Can't post links, because I don't have enough reputation. You can search for `sync` by the user `calzoneman`and `syncplay` by `Uriziel`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would suggest using a server to stream the video content, and therefore can be changed for everyone by one person. Java has a fairly good server library; which is quite easy to use, especially for beginners. Though you can use java alongside another programming language which suits your server needs.

Though I would like to point out that java; due to its current non-universal state could cause complications; however if that is not a problem my suggestion holds.

C# on the other hand could also be good for the client side, seeing as it has the largest IO compatibility/library with windows (The most often operating system used).

**Suggestions:** 
*Java:*
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077634/java-web-development/how-to-get-started-with-server-side-java.html 
*C#:*http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server